# Animate ParametricPlot3D for two different parametric equations

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, animation

I want to write a computer program to generate 3-D plots (with x-y-t axes) to demonstrate the evolution of the two missiles in the following case:

i. $x = 100t$, $y = 80t-16t^2$ for $0\leq t\leq 5$ for the incoming missile

ii. $x= 500-200(t-2)$, $y = 80(t-2)-16(t-2)^2$ for $2\leq t\leq 7$ for the interceptor missile

I coded it like this:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, 60 t}, {500 - 200 (s - 2), 
80 (s - 2) - 16 (s - 2)^2, s}}, {t, 0, 5}, {s, 2, 7}]
```

The problem is that How can I animate this two functions in 3D form (with x-y-t axes)? I want it to display two moving objects,so i can see if there's any collision.By the way,please help me to correct the code if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you want an animation parameterized by the time $t$? This would do it in an interactive way:

```
With[{missileSize = 10},
 Manipulate[
  Graphics[{
    {Red,
     Disk[
      {100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2}, missileSize
      ]},
    {Blue,
     Disk[
      {500 - 200 (t - 2), 80 (t - 2) - 16 (t - 2)^2}, missileSize
      ]}
    },
   Frame -> True,
   GridLines -> Automatic,
   PlotRange -> {{0, 800}, {-200, 400}},
   AspectRatio -> Automatic],
  {t, 0, 7}]
 ]
```

Alternatively, you could create an animation like this:

```
t = Table[Graphics[{
     {Red,
      Disk[
       {100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2}, 10
       ]},
     {Blue,
      Disk[
       {500 - 200 (t - 2), 80 (t - 2) - 16 (t - 2)^2}, 10
       ]}
     },
    Frame -> True,
    PlotRange -> {{0, 800}, {-200, 400}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic],
   {t, 0, 5, .1}];

ListAnimate[t]
```

[image: missile animation]

The animation above was created with

```
Export["missiles.gif", t]
```

**Edit**

Since it was asked in the comment, I'll add the 3D analogue here, too - although Verbeia already did something like it with `Manipulate`:

```
xMin = 0;
xMax = 800;
yMin = -200;
yMax = 200;
zMin = -200;
zMax = 400;
ground = {Green, 
   Polygon[{{xMin, yMin, zMin}, {xMin, yMax, zMin}, {xMax, yMax, 
      zMin}, {xMax, yMin, zMin}}]};

t = Table[
   Graphics3D[{ground, {Red, 
      Sphere[{100 t, 0, 80 t - 16 t^2}, 10]}, {Blue, 
      Sphere[{500 - 200 (t - 2), 0, 80 (t - 2) - 16 (t - 2)^2}, 10]}},
     Boxed -> True, 
    PlotRange -> {{xMin, xMax}, {yMin, yMax}, {zMin, zMax}}], {t, 0, 
    6, .1}];

ListAnimate[t]
```

[image: bullets in 3d]

If you compare to the 2D code, I just replaced `Disk` by `Sphere`, made the height the `z` coordinate and set the `y` coordinate of the projectiles to `0`.

The other changes are just small tweaks: I defined the plot range as variables so I can use them to define a rectangular `Polygon` representing the `ground`. Instead of the `Framed` option, there is the `Boxed` option (which can also be omitted or set to `False`).

Comment: thank you for your answer,it's pretty clear and understandable. but how can i plot it in 3D form?I have tried using Graphic3D@Sphere as in Verbeia's answer, but i couldnt make it.

Answer (score 9):

What you could do with `ParametricPlot3D` is to observe the trajectories in the $\{x,y,t\}$ space:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[{30 t, 100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2}, {t, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ParametricPlot3D[{30 t, (500 - 200 ( t - 2)),  80 (t - 2) - 16 (t - 2)^2}, {t, 2, 7}]]
```

[image]

(the $t$ coordinate has been dilated to get a better aspect ratio)

Answer (score 8):

This version combines the `Manipulate` approach suggested by Jens with the `ParametricPlot3D` approach used by belisarius, to get a version with flying "cannonballs" made out of `Sphere` primitives, as well as their trajectories to that point (`tt`), plotted using `ParametricPlot3D`.

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{{100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, 60 t}, {500 - 200 t, 
      80 t - 16 t^2, t + 2}}, {t, 0, tt}, PlotRangePadding -> 20, 
    PlotRange -> {{-1500, 1000}, {-800, 100}, {0, 600}}], 
   Graphics3D@Sphere[{100 tt, 80 tt - 16 tt^2, 60 tt}, 15], 
   Graphics3D@Sphere[{500 - 200 tt, 80 tt - 16 tt^2, tt + 2}, 15]}], 
 {tt, 0.1, 10}]
```

The explicit `PlotRange` stops the box resizing. I included the `PlotRangePadding` option so that the cannonballs don't get cut off at the edge of the plot.

[image]

belisarius has pointed out to me that you can avoid working out the total plot range using a “hidden graph” technique.

```
Manipulate[ 
Show[{ParametricPlot3D[{{100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, 60 t}, 
  {500 - 200 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, t + 2}}, {t, 0, 10}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.2], PlotStyle -> None], 
 ParametricPlot3D[{{100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, 60 t}, 
  {500 - 200 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, t + 2}}, {t, 0, tt}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[0.2]], 
 Graphics3D@Sphere[{100 tt, 80 tt - 16 tt^2, 60 tt}, 55], 
 Graphics3D@Sphere[{500 - 200 tt, 80 tt - 16 tt^2, tt + 2}, 55]}], 
{tt, 0.1, 10}]
```

To be honest I would never have expected these trajectories to meet because the following yields an empty list (no solutions).

```
Solve[Thread[{100 t, 80 t - 16 t^2, 60 t} == {500 - 200 (t), 
    80 (t) - 16 (t)^2, t + 2}], t]
```

Comment: I had thought of using the space shuttle example data for this... but decided that would be too macabre.