# Composing an image with a plot

Tags: plotting, image-processing, image

I'm trying to illustrate the solutions to a textbook problem dealing with quadratic functions.

This will involve plotting a quadratic and overlaying the plot and the image.

Here is the textbook scan.....[image]

The idea of the problem is to find several possible quadratic models that would go through the hoop.

I imported this image into a variable,  call it  img1

I wanted to establish a "baseline" so I started with a simple plot,  x intercepts of 0 and 18,  and vertex at (9,14).   I know, NOT  a solution to the problem but I wanted to see how the plot and image would match up.

I created the plot

```
g2 = Plot[-14/81 x (x - 18), {x, -1, 19}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

Then I put them together and tweaked the placement of the plot based on the image size.

```
ImageCompose[img1, g2, {983/2, 811/2}]
```

Which gives me this...

[image]

The vertex is in the right place,  but the axes don't line up.

Sorry if this is a dumb question,  I'm not at all sure how I could get my plot to match the background image so the axes in the image would be the same as the axes in my plot....

Do I need to scale my plot,  or scale my image..  or something obvious that I am missing.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: If you right click a graphic or an image, there's a tool to "get coordinates".  You can click on a number of points, then use Control-C to copy the coordinates.  This can be helpful for aligning the image coordinate system with `Plot`'s coordinate system.  Alternatively, instead of using an image with a grid on it, could use only an image of a boy with a basketball, and place that image on the plot using the `Epilog` option.  You could also place a basket :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs I just read your comment after I did exactly that for my answer. :)

Comment: The answers with `Manipulate` reminded me of this question: [Animate ParametricPlot3D for two different parametric equations](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4859/245)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
(* clip white borders *)
img = ImageCrop[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/La8Zs.jpg"]];

Plot[-14/81 x (x - 18), {x, -2, 19},
     PlotRange -> {-2, 16}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick, Dashed], 
     Prolog -> {Texture[img],
                Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], Scaled[{0, 1}]},
                        VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]},
     Ticks -> None]
```

[image: plot with custom background]

Notes:

- If you want to fit in an image as background, you will often want to trim margins; `ImageCrop[]` is a good function for the purpose.
- Luckily, your background image has its own coordinate system; you can then adjust `PlotRange` appropriately.
- `Prolog` is most useful for putting primitives in the background.
- `Scaled[]` ensures that the background textured polygon is scaled appropriately with respect to the plot range.

Comment: Thanks so much,  that helps a TON.  I'll be using this question in just a few hours,  so I can get it to work NOW, and think about some of the ideas you mentioned.   I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Such a superior answer. It. Hurts. Me. :)

Comment: I know we shouldn't write comments like "Thanks!" and so on, but thanks. That has just saved me probably a week of work and workarounds.

Comment: @yohbs, you're welcome! I'm glad my attempt saved you some effort. :)

Answer (score 11):

**EDIT:** (see below for old version)

New version with alpha channels, the option to lock the graph at the ball, adjustable player position and a button to remove player and basket:

```
setalpha[im_] := 
 Module[{mask = 
    ChanVeseBinarize[im, TargetColor -> {1., 1., 1.}, 
     "LengthPenalty" -> 10]},
  mask = Blur[Erosion[ColorNegate[mask], 2], 5];
  Rasterize[SetAlphaChannel[im, mask], Background -> None]]

basket = setalpha[
   Import["http://www.hdwallpaperspk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/ basketball_clipart.jpg"]];
guy = setalpha[
   Import["http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/ifm/produkte-medien/basketball_200.png"]];

Manipulate[
 Plot[If[locked, (-c - b pos[[1]] + pos[[2]])/pos[[1]]^2, a] x^2 + 
   b x + c, {x, 0, 16}, PlotRange -> {{0, 17}, {0, 14}},
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
  FrameLabel -> {"Distance from Back of hoop (ft)", "Heigth (ft)"},
  GridLines -> {Range@16, Range@14},
  Prolog -> {Inset[If[show, basket, ""], {0.5, 8}, Top, 1], 
    Inset[If[show, guy, ""], pos, Top, 2.5]}],
 Item@Row[{"a  ", 
    Dynamic@Slider[Dynamic@a, {1, 10}, Enabled -> ! locked]}], 
 Item@Row[{"b  ", Dynamic@Slider[Dynamic@b, {1, 10}]}],
 Item@Row[{"c  ", Dynamic@Slider[Dynamic@c, {1, 10}]}],
 {{pos, {16, 6}}, Locator},
 {{locked, True, "Lock graph at ball"}, {True, False}},
 {{show, True, "Show player and basket"}, {True, False}},
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

---

Old version:

Alternatively, you can also create the whole thing completely in *Mathematica*. I also added `Manipulate` for fun:

```
basket = Import[
        "http://www.hdwallpaperspk.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/basketball_clipart.jpg"];
guy = Import["http://www.tu-chemnitz.de/ifm/produkte-medien/basketball_200.png"];

Manipulate[
 Plot[-(c x - b)^2 + a, {x, 0, 16},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 17}, {0, 14}},
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> 500,
  BaseStyle -> {20, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"},
  FrameLabel -> {"Distance from Back of hoop (ft)", "Heigth (ft)"},
  GridLines -> {Range@16, Range@14},
  Prolog -> {Inset[basket, {0.5, 8}, Top, 1],
    Inset[guy, {16, 6}, Top, 2.5]}],
 {a, 8, 20}, {b, 1, 10}, {c, 0.1, 1}]
```

Comment: Wow!  Looks fantastic,  I'll check that out later today when I have time.  This is nice since I could have buttons to show the "guy" and "hoop",  take them off once the student gets into the problem.    Really nice.  I really appreciate seeing solutions like this since I can really connect to the commands being used since they apply directly to my problem.  Thanks for your time!

Comment: Now the player only needs a tad alpha channel to [remove the white background](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8041703)

Comment: @YvesKlett the new version comes with alpha channels. Thanks for the link, btw. It's really useful! :)

Answer (score 5):

I enlarge the image canvas if throw flies outside.

```
together[i, {4, 22, 10}]
```

[image: Throw 1]

Parabola with zeroes `x1`, `x2` and vertex at `{(x1 + x2)/2, y3}`:

```
y[{x1_, x2_, y3_}, x_] := -4 (x - x1) (x - x2) y3/(x1 - x2)^2

i = ImageCrop@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/La8Zs.jpg";
```

Note `ImageCrop`, it ensured me constant `ImageDimensions[i]/{21, 18}` pixels for each unit.

```
together[i_Image, {x1_, x2_, y3_}] :=
 Module[{p, r, u, v},
  {u, v} = ImageDimensions@i/{21., 18.};
  p = Plot[y[{x1, x2, y3}, x], {x, x1, x2},
    PlotRange -> {{x1, x2}, {0, y3}},
    AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> None,
    PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsoluteThickness[3]]];
  r = PlotRange /. AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange];
  p = Image[p, ImageSize -> u Abs[Subtract @@ First[r]]];
  p = SetAlphaChannel[p, Dilation[ColorNegate@Binarize@p, 1]];
  With[{pl = Max[0, -1 - x1]},
   ImageCompose[ImagePad[i, {
      Round[u {pl, Max[0, x2 - 18]}],
      Round[v {0, Max[0, y3 - 15]}]}, White], p,
    {u (2 + pl + r[[1, 1]]), 2 v}, {0, 0}]]]

together[i, {0, 18, 14}]
```

[image: throw2]

Comment: This is really helpful,  since it shows a lot of nice ways to massage the imported image,  as well as the function to create a quadratic from zeroes and the y value of the vertex.   Things like that are very helpful and I don't often think of doing that.