# Intersecting parabolas in an image

Tags: image-processing

I have a friend who is a math teacher (like me)  and while out cycling took this picture.

[image: parabolas]

The idea would be to create the equations of the quadratics that model the bridges and super-impose them on the picture.  (assuming the bridge supports ARE quadratics,  but they should be "close enough" for high school...)

I have no idea what is possible with "image processing",  so here is possibly a stupid question.  The picture is taken from an angle, not sure what it is, but lets say about 30 degrees.  I know it won't make much difference to the answer, but is there some image processing command that would skew this image to simulate the picture being taken from "the middle of the river"?

After that,  I know I would use some kind of "image compose" to put together some plots of parabolas and the photo.

[This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23003/composing-an-image-with-a-plot) deals with that ,  but I'd be happy to have further input on that process.

As always,  appreciate any input,  I learn the most when the problem is something I am actively working on

Comment: Someone doing more or less the same: http://passyworldofmathematics.com/sydney-harbour-bridge-mathematics/

Comment: Thanks for that,  that's a great resource.  I will have to see if there is data online for the bridge in my friend's photo  (St. George's bridge in Calgary, AB)

Comment: You could look into `ImagePerspectiveTransformation` and related functions, but rectification (or the search for the right parameters) will most likely not be trivial. Besides the angle, the focal length would be another possible factor.

Comment: You probably mean [St. Patrick's](http://www.designscene.net/2010/05/st-patricks-footbridge-in-calgary.html), and the arches are (almost) surely not parabolic from that perspective since they lean inwards. :D . Google Power

Comment: Yes,  you got me there... I got the name from my friend (a Calgarian!)   I guess even if you  live there you may know all the names... I don't know all the bridge names for Edmonton (where I live).  Thanks for the correction and link!

Comment: More construction details http://www.tekla.com/global-bim-awards-2013/steel-saint-patricks-bridge.html

Comment: Are you really sure you need to perform such a correction? My intuition tells me that an isometrically distorted parabola is still a parabola. Lens curvature will be a factor that needs correcting, but I don't believe perspective is.

Comment: I tried to do a "brute force" parabola creation on the un-edited image.  I'm no mathematician but I could NOT get the last parabola (farthest to the left) to match the bridge, but the one farthest to the right matched "perfectly".  You could be right, but based on the answer below, my intuition tells me that the distortion  WILL require correction...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is probably using `FindGeometricTransform`: For that, you'd need a number of points in a plane in the image, and their corresponding coordinates in some 2d "world" coordinate system. To illustrate, I'll pick 4 points in the image that are (more or less) the corners of a rectangle:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VDdh.png"];
pts = {{419, 157}, {933, 140}, {937, 276}, {420, 259}};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pts],
 Dynamic[Show[img,
   Graphics[{
     {EdgeForm[Red], Transparent, Polygon[pts]},
     {
      Red,
      MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 14], #1, {1, 1}] &, pts]
      }
     }]]]]
```

[image]

(It's hard to estimate the vanishing point in this image, so I'm not sure how accurate these points are...)

The I'll say that these points correspond to the corners of this rectangle:

```
width = 100;
height = 20;
ptsFlat = {{0, 0}, {width, 0}, {width, height}, {0, height}};
```

and let Mathematica do the real work:

```
{err, transform} = 
 FindGeometricTransform[pts, ptsFlat, 
  TransformationClass -> "Perspective"]
```

Now `transform` is a function that maps points from my `ptsFlat`-coordinate system to image coordinates:

```
grid = Table[transform[{x, y}], {x, 0, width, 5}, {y, 0, height, 5}];
Show[img,
 Graphics[
  {
   Red, Line /@ grid, Line /@ Transpose[grid]
   }]]
```

[image]

You could just pass this function to `ImageTransformation` and "un-distort" the image:

```
ImageTransformation[img, transform, 800, PlotRange -> All, 
 DataRange -> Full]
```

[image]

But the result isn't that spectacular: The projection is correct (at least ignoring radial distortion) for points in the same plane as the bridge, but stuff before/behind the bridge is distorted and in the wrong place. I wouldn't say that it's completely impossible to get the rest of the image projected the right way; But it'll definitely be quicker to rent a boat and take a picture from the middle of the river.

However, it's now simple enough to project our coordinate system *into* the image. I'll again choose 3 points on one of the bridge arcs:

```
ptsBridge = {{429, 163}, {646, 258}, {859, 245}};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[ptsBridge],
 Dynamic[Show[img,
   Graphics[{
     {
      Red, Point[ptsBridge],
      MapIndexed[Text[Style[#2[[1]], 14], #1, {1, 1}] &, ptsBridge]
      }
     }]]]]
```

...map these to our 2d "world" coordinate system:

```
ptsParabola = InverseFunction[transform] /@ ptsBridge;
```

fit a parabola to these 3 points:

```
parabola = Fit[ptsParabola, {1, x, x^2}, x];
```

and draw that parabola into the image

```
parabolaPts = 
  transform /@ 
   Table[{x, parabola}, {x, Min[ptsParabola[[All, 1]]], 
     Max[ptsParabola[[All, 1]]], 0.1}];

Show[img,
 Graphics[
  {
   Gray, Line /@ grid, Line /@ Transpose[grid],
   Red, Point[ptsBridge],
   Line[transform /@ {{#[[1]], 0}, #}] & /@ ptsParabola,
   Dashed, Line[parabolaPts]
   }]]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant,helpful,  I appreciate your "step by step" discussion,  I learned a lot.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my try to make the parabola identification more or less automatic. It is not great but it almost works!

I was only able to find the largest parabola, maybe cleaning up the image more, you or others, might be able to find the other parabolas (maybe with `ImageCorrelation[]` )
I won't do the perspective transform, another answer dealt with that.

```
 img=<imageabove>;
 imdim=ImageDimensions[img];

 parabola={#[[2]], 408 - #[[1]]} & /@Position[ImageData[DeleteSmallComponents@EdgeDetect[img,2,0.5]],1];
 fit=NonlinearModelFit[parabola,a+b*x+c*x^2,{a,b,c},x];


newpoints=({imdim[[2]] - #[[1]], #[[2]]} -> 1 & /@ (DeleteCases[
 Table[{Floor@fit[xd], xd}, {xd, 1, imdim[[1]], 1}], 
 x_ /; x[[1]] < 1]))[[1 ;; ]];

imgparabola=Dilation[Image[SparseArray[newpoints, Reverse@imdim, 0]], 2];

HighlightImage[img, imgparabola]
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing answer,  I will have to experiment with edge detection for other photos!