# Removing Perspective Distortion

Tags: image-processing, image

Below is my input:

[image]

I would like to remove perspective distortion from the image.

Expected output below:

[image]

Comment: Related: [(5676)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5676/121), [(13918)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13918/121), [(18167)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18167/121) [(21059)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21059/121),  [(24890)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24890/121), [(26268)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/26268/121)

Comment: Another related post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63890/131

Comment: Beside that we have a zillion image processing questions which are related to what you try, your question doesn't show even minimal effort. In its current state, this post doesn't reach the required quality for this site. I vote to close this. -1