# Find lane lines

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

A crucial step in self-driving car is to detect lane lines. I'm wondering whether this can be achieved robustly using Mathematica's rich image processing tools.

For example how can I take camera image of this (taken from [here](https://github.com/ralphie9224/CarND-LaneLines-P1))

[image]

and detect the two lane lines like this

[image]

I tried to use the `ImageLines` to find the lines, but its seems difficult to 
pick up the left lane line:

```
img = Import[
  "https://github.com/ralphie9224/CarND-LaneLines-P1/raw/master/test_\
images/solidWhiteRight.jpg"];

lines = ImageLines[img, 0.4, 0.8, 
   Method -> {"Hough", "Segmented" -> True}, MaxFeatures -> 2];

HighlightImage[img, {Pink, Thickness[0.005], Line /@ lines}]
```

[image]

I also tried to apply a mask before running through `ImageLines`,

```
polygon = {{510, 92}, {337, 404}, {337, 581}, {510, 960}};
pixelIndex = 
  Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}, {j, 1, 
    ImageDimensions[img][[1]]}];
mask = 
 Image[Replace[
   RegionMember[Polygon@polygon, pixelIndex], {True -> 1, 
    False -> 0}, -1]];
masked = ImageMultiply[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"], mask];
```

But it is still difficult to pick up the left lane line

```
lines = ImageLines[masked, Method -> {"Hough", "Segmented" -> True}, 
   MaxFeatures -> 5];
HighlightImage[masked, {Orange, Line /@ lines}]
```

[image]

Comment: In the real world, lane lines are often poorly maintained to the point of being worn away completely in some jurisdictions (like mine in Massachusetts).  Or they are obscured by fallen leaves, snow, road repairs, or rain at night (i.e., by lights reflecting off the wet sheen) or heavy traffic.    So really, self driving cars need to function without relying on or expecting to find lane lines even on roads where they are assumed to be at least theoretically present.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`ImageLines` expects an input image where the "line" pixels are white and the other pixels are dark, so unless you're looking at bubble chamber images, you're expected to do some preprocessing, like this:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJBKi.jpg"];
binary = MorphologicalBinarize[img, .9];
HighlightImage[img, binary]
```

[image]

With this image, we can find the lane lines:

```
lines = ImageLines[Thinning@binary];
HighlightImage[img, {Pink, Thickness[0.005], Line /@ lines}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I played around a bit and the main functions I think help are `RemoveBackground`, `Binarize` and `GradientFilter`.  Finally, using the right arguments to `ImageLines` help you decide how distinct the lines need to be.  The code I ended up with is this:

*Note img is your original image*

```
(*DeleteSmallComponents removes the small artifacts from binarizing*)
filtered = DeleteSmallComponents[
   (*Brightens the processed image*)
   ImageAdjust[

    (*Takes the change in brightness, can be used as an edge filter*)
    GradientFilter[

     Binarize[

      (*Removes the sky as its brightness is confusing ImageLines*)
      RemoveBackground[
       img,
       Lighter@Blue
       ],

       (*Binarizing threshold*)
      .84
      ],
      (*GradientFilter pixel radius*)
     1
     ]
    ],

   (*Number of small components to delete*)
   20
   ];


lines = ImageLines[
  (*Another gradient filter to define a bit more clearly*)
  GradientFilter[filtered, 1], 
  (*Threshold for lines*)
  0.03, 
  (*How distinct/different the lines should be*)
  0.1
];

HighlightImage[img, {Pink, Thickness[0.005], Line /@ lines}]
```

[image: RoadLines]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering why did you delete your answer in the first place. I think the answer is great and I and many others may found it very useful. I cannot ping you within the chat so I asked several people with access to moderator tools for help to bring back your answer.

Comment: Oh, thank you :)  I tested it and it seemed pretty inefficient, especially compared to the other answer so I thought it would be better to keep the answer list clear.  I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers are based on the `ImageLines` function, here I'm providing an answer based on the geometric transformations, which can work in curved roads as well.

We take an image of a straight road first

```
i = ImageTrim[Import["https://github.com/udacity/CarND-Advanced-Lane-Lines/raw/master/test_images/straight_lines2.jpg"], {{0, 50}, {1280, 718}}];
{width, height} = ImageDimensions[i];
```

Then use the same method as in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135974/1364) to remove the perspective distortion from the image. We define a perspective distorted rectangle in the original image and then find a geometric transformation that transforms this distorted rectangle to an undistorted one. The same transformation will take us from the original image to the undistorted image.

```
pts1 = {{289, 3}, {431, 106}, {869, 106}, {1034, 3}};
wdWidth = 200;
aspect = 5;
wdHeight = 80;
pts2 = {{width/2 - wdWidth/2, 0}, {width/2 - wdWidth/2, 
    wdHeight}, {width/2 + wdWidth/2, wdHeight}, {width/2 + wdWidth/2, 
    0}};
t = FindGeometricTransform[pts2, pts1][[2]]
```

This compares the original and the undistorted image

```
Row@{Show[i, 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, Point[pts1], Transparent, 
     EdgeForm[Red], Polygon[pts1]}], ImageSize -> Large], 
  Show[ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i, t, PlotRange -> Full], 
   Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Green, Point[pts2], Transparent, 
     EdgeForm[Green], Polygon[pts2]}], ImageSize -> Large]}
```

[image]

Now we can binarize the image and get the lane pixels

```
iwrap = ImageTrim[
  ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i, t, 
   PlotRange -> Full], {{width/2 - wdWidth/2 - wdWidth/4, 
    0}, {width/2 + wdWidth/2 + wdWidth/4, height}}];
ibinary = Binarize[iwrap];
{newWidth, newHeight} = Reverse[ImageData[ibinary] // Dimensions];
idx = Position[ImageData[ibinary], 1];
leftIdx = Select[idx, #[[2]] < 150 &];
rightIdx = Complement[idx, leftIdx];
```

and fit the pixel positions using quadratic form.

```
leftModel = Fit[leftIdx, {x^2, x, 1}, x]
rightModel = Fit[rightIdx, {x^2, x, 1}, x]
```

This shows the lane lines in the undistorted image

```
Show[ImagePerspectiveTransformation[i, t, PlotRange -> Full], 
 Plot[{leftModel, rightModel}, {x, 1, 670}, PlotStyle -> Thick] /. 
  Line[pts_] :> 
   Line[pts /. {x_, y_} -> {y + (width - newWidth)/2, height - x}], 
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Now we can change back to the perspective image using the inverse transform and plot the lane

```
plane = Cases[
   Plot[{leftModel, rightModel}, {x, 1, 670}, PlotStyle -> Thick] /. 
    Line[pts_] :> 
     Line[pts /. {x_, y_} -> {y + (width - newWidth)/2, height - x}], 
   Line[pt_] :> Line[pt], ∞];
t2 = FindGeometricTransform[pts1, pts2][[2]];

Show[i, Graphics[{Green, Opacity[0.25], 
   Polygon[Join[Reverse[#[[1]]], #[[2]]] &@(plane /. 
       Line[pts_] :> t2 /@ pts)], Blue, Opacity[0.5], 
   Thickness[0.003], plane /. Line[pts_] :> Line[t2 /@ pts]}]]
```

[image]

Since this method doesn't depend on the `ImageLines`, it can also work for a curved road:

[image]