# Plotting points with Overlay (No axis! & Optional)

Tags: overlay

```
With[{
img = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], {escala}]},
   size = 1000;
    escala = 500;
     proporcion = size/escala;

  celda = 200;
n = size/celda;
sub = Subdivide[-1, 1, n];

With[{
    dimensions = ImageDimensions[img]},
        Manipulate[

    grid = 
Graphics[{}, GridLines -> {sub, sub}, PlotRangePadding -> None, 
 GridLinesStyle -> 
  Directive[White, Thick, Dashing[Tiny], Opacity[0.5]], 
 ImageSize -> ImageDimensions@img];
    Overlay[{img, grid}],

 {{pt, dimensions/2}, Locator, Appearance -> disk[r, White, pt]},
{{pt2, dimensions/2}, Locator, Appearance -> disk[r, Red, pt2]},

{{r, .05, Style["r", Bold, 15]}, .02, .5, .01, ImageSize -> 500},
ControlPlacement -> Top, 
Initialization :> (disk[r_, color_, pt_] := 
  Graphics[{{Opacity[.4, color], EdgeForm[Black], 
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[r]]}, {Thick, 
     Line[{Scaled@{.5 - r/8, .5}, Scaled@{.5 + r/8, .5}}], 
     Line[{Scaled@{.5, .5 - r/8}, Scaled@{.5, .5 + r/8}}]}, {Text[
      Framed[Style[Row[pt, ","], Bold, 12], FrameMargins -> Tiny, 
       Background -> Opacity[.4, White]], Scaled@{.5, .52 + r}]}},
    ImageSize -> dimensions])]]]
```

I have a big amount of points like coordinates (x,y). I want to plot them over the image WITHOUT the axis.

In this case the img is 500x500 so a point like (250,250) will be near the right-sup corner.

The idea is to plot any coordinate over the image but not compulsory, for example:

```
P1=List[{0,0},{100,200}];
P2=List[{0,0},{-200,-300]];
```

I want to choose which P will appear over the img with OVERLAY,not everything at the same time.

Comment: Have you seen `HighlightImage[]`?

Comment: It is not what i am looking for.

I am using the main images like a "map" and i want to add points like references. The points represent different kind of things. For example "Cities" or "monuments" or "parks", i don't want to show them all at the same time, and they have to be in a specific coordinate.

Comment: Then, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23003)?

Comment: Yes but it is not what i am looking for.

I am using this:

    Puntos= Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], White, 
    Point[{Scaled[{0, .5}], Scaled[{1, 0.5}]}]}];
    
    Grilla={Nogrid,Grid,Puntos};

     Overlay[{img, grillas[[selector]]}],

The problem is that "scaled" doesn't work well, i want to use the absolute coordinates (the "map" is 6200x6200) when i introduce Scaled(0,0) the point appears in (120,120)