# Optimize this computation of Liapunov exponent

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion

**Introduction**

In dynamical systems there is an important exponent called *Liapunov exponent*. I'm trying to create a visual representation of Liapunov exponent for *one dimension finite-difference equations*. For example, the most common equation is the *logistic map*: $(1)\quad x_{n + 1} = rx_{n}(1 - x_{n})$, where $x_{n}$ is the $n$-th iteration of (1), we define $x_0 = x$, $n$ goes from 0 to $\infty$, and $r$ goes from 0 to 4. Equation (1) is discrete, but we can consider the continuous function $(2)\quad f(x) = rx(1 - x)$ in order to do all the computations (I will not prove nothing here), then $(3)\quad f'(x) = r(1 - 2x)$.

Finally, Liapunov exponent is

\begin{equation}
    (4) \hspace{1em} \lambda(r) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left\{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 0}^{n - 1} \ln \left|f'(x_i)\right|\right\}
\end{equation}

and we can define any other $f(x)$ depending the finite-difference equations. For (1) the graph is:

[image: A nice description]

---

**The code**

I want a good approximations of this exponent and the following code plots is that way, but I want a smooth graph and it takes a lot of time.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

ITERATIONS = 100; (* Fidelity *)
F[x_, r_] := r*x*(1 - x); (* Logistic map *)
f[x_, r_] := r*(1 - 2*x); (* Derivate *)
λ[r_, u_] := (1/ITERATIONS)*
  Sum[Log[Abs[f[Nest[F[#, r] &, u, i], r]]], {i, 0, 
    ITERATIONS - 1}]; (* Liapunov exponent approximation *)

Plot[
 Legended[
  Style[λ[r, RandomReal[]], Black, Thickness[0.001]], 
  Style["Fidelity = 100", FontSize -> 20]
  ],
 {r, 3 , 4},
 PlotTheme -> "Scientific",
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.003], FontSize -> 20, Black],
 ImageSize -> Large,
 AspectRatio -> 1/2,
 PlotRange -> {{3, 4}, {-1, 1}},
 Axes -> True,
 AxesStyle -> Directive[Thickness[0.002], Blue]
 ]
```

[image: Another nice description]

[image: More incredible description]

[image: I don´t have friends, if you read this, pls, comment this post]

I know this problem can be solved with a "manual `Nest`" because `Nest` itself takes a lot of time with large number of iterations. **How can I improve this code?** **How can I use a function like a counter, but, a `Nest` counter?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using symbolic `Nest` which is extremely slow. Anyway, it is more efficient to use `RecurrenceTable`. The plot below generates in less than 2 seconds with 20000 iterations.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

ITERATIONS = 20000; (*Fidelity*)
F[x_, r_] := r*x*(1. - x); (*Logistic map*)
f[x_, r_] := r*(1 - 2*x);
xlist[x0_?NumericQ, r_] := RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == r*x[n]*(1 - x[n]), x[0] == x0}, 
  x, {n, 0, ITERATIONS - 1}]
lambda[r_, xx_?NumericQ] := Mean[xlist[xx, r] // f[#, r] & // Abs // Log]

Plot[lambda[r, RandomReal[]], {r, 3, 4}]
```

[image]

You can superimpose with the original plot (see [18767](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23010/18767)):

```
img = ImageCrop@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBrkG.png"]
img = ImageTrim[img, {{60, 65}, {475, 420}}]
Plot[lambda[r, RandomReal[]], {r, 3, 4}, AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 ImageSize -> 1000, PlotRange -> {{3, 4}, {-1, 1}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.005], 
 Prolog -> {Texture[img], 
   Polygon[{Scaled[{0, 0}], Scaled[{1, 0}], Scaled[{1, 1}], 
     Scaled[{0, 1}]}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I had never seen before the notation ?NumericQ, can you explain it to me? I found this [Reference](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html)

Comment: It's a Pattern, it means that the function is only defined if NumericQ returns True for the argument (= the argument is numerical value). Try for instance `f[x_NumericQ] := x^2` and `f[1]` then `f[abc]`. The latter returns unevaluated.

Comment: @tajiri_numero_1 Is it correct that the system is stable iff $\lambda <0$? $r$ would be a parameter of a dynamical system (such as mass or length)?

Comment: Yes, if $\lambda < 0$ represents a stable behavior, $\lambda > 0$ represents a chaotic behavior and $\lambda = 0$ is a marginal value. $r$ in Logistic map could represent a lot of different things and it is given by the problem. In biology, for example, $r$ could represent a parameter of birth and dead of a population.